# Displaying button in subview in a stackview

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, uiview

I am trying to display the facebook login button in UIView but am running into some issues.  I have a UIView that is currently within a stackview and I think that's causing some issues.

This screenshot shows the UIView I am trying to add the button into:

[image]

And this is where the FB button is displaying: 
[image]

So I have two issues. I want the FB login button to fit the size of the UIView completely, and also be in the same location.

I have the following piece of code:

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

```
let fbLoginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()

let convertToSuperView = loginStackView.convert(fbLoginButton.frame, to: self.view)
fbLoginButton.frame = CGRect(x: fbLoginView.bounds.origin.x, y: fbLoginView.bounds.origin.y, width: convertToSuperView.width, height: convertToSuperView.height)
fbLoginButton.clipsToBounds = true
fbLoginView.addSubview(fbLoginButton)
```

}

From reading documentation I got that the bounds is for getting the points at which something is located on the screen. I tried converting the bounds of the UIView from within the stackView to the parent view, and then giving the button the same frame as the UIView.

This clearly is not working so some assistance would be helpful. If you could explain why issues like this happen that would help me tackle issues like this in the future.

EDIT: Thanks to comments from @pierce I got it to look a little better by adding the fbLoginButton as a subview to fbLoginView.

Here I still have one issue, the frame isn't equal in size to the UIView

[image]

I also updated the code snippet above to reflect this. I have tried playing around with the sizing, but run into issues.

When I set the rect width/height to use the fbLoginView width and height, the login button is WAY too large, even with clipsToBounds its too large. When I try to center the button, it disappears.

Comment: Are you wanting to add the login button to the loginStackView?

Comment: Yes I'd like to have it be in the view of the fbLobingView which is within the loginStackView @Pierce

Comment: Well one problem is you're adding the button to the main view of the `UIViewController`, so when you set the frame, you're setting it to the frame relative to the entire screen. Try the last line as `loginStackView.addSubview(fbLoginButton)`

Comment: Or instead of `loginStackView`, try whatever the name is of the container view you wish to house the actual button.

Comment: sorry I didn't read your comment completely. If you want it to be a subview of the fbLoginView, say `fbLoginView.addSubview(fbLoginButton)`

Comment: You always want to make sure you add the button (or view, or whatever the case may be) as a subview of the view you want to actually contain the button. When you set the frame of a view (or in this case, button), it will set that frame relative to it's superview. So when you're setting it here, it's setting it at coordinates (0, 0) of the entire ViewController's view, not just the fbLoginView. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you that really helps and make sense. I updated my post to include your comments. You can see that the button displays in the correct positions (origin seems good) but the height/width is not ok. I'd like to to be larger. If I use the fbLoginView's height and width it doesnt like that and gets all screwed up. Whats the general gist when trying to size within a subview? @Pierce

Comment: Just out of curiosity, try this and tell me if it works: `fbLoginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: fbLoginView.frame.width, height: fbLoginView.frame.height)`. If that still messes up add this line of code at the end of `viewDidLoad`. When you run it, tell me what prints I'm just curious how big the fbLoginView's area actually is set to: `print("fbLoginView height, width: \(fbLoginView.frame.height), \(fbLoginView.frame.width)")`

Comment: it messes up and the output is fbLoginView height, width: 1000.0, 1000.0 @Pierce

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132659/discussion-between-pierce-and-mufc).